# Avoid download file dialog box in Python/selenium automation

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I am using this code to automate a flow which will download a Winzip file without prompt.
But it does not seem to work

```
profile = webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk',("application/zip,
                                                   application/octet-stream"))
profile.set_preference('browser.download.folderList', 2)
profile.set_preference('browser.download.dir', '/home/jack/DOWNLOAD')
self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
```

I still see the dialog box being opened while automation.

Comment: if you disable prompt manually on the first download, does it work correctly for the downloads after that?

Comment: @root No I am not able to do it manually as well. Also, `browser.download.dir` is not present in `about:config`

Comment: if you are on linux what does the following command give you  `curl -I https://www.downloadadress.com/ | grep Content-Type `

Comment: Have you've tried `application/x-zip-compressed` and `application/x-rar-compressed` as MIME types as well?

Comment: @RocketDonkey Yes I tried them but in vein.

Comment: @RocketDonkey `browser.download.dir` is missing in Firefpx 11 in Ubuntu. Is that the issue?

Comment: @root I manually changed the Firefox preferences and now download is happening without prompt. But while automation, file is not getting downloaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this situation by extracting the `href` of the download link and using the python `urllib` module.

Using the below code, one can download the file and save it in a different file name as well.

```
import urllib
url = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Download").get_attribute("href");
urllib.urlretrieve(url, "saveasfilename")
```

Comment: @cppcoder can we provide the destination folder as well?